# Set application log verbosity on ASP.Net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have implemented some debugging code in my ASP.Net MVC based application by using the `Trace.TraceInformation` statement.

How can I configure my web.config or IIS7.5 server to enable logging of these statements, and where can I go to view them?

Answer (score 2):

**To enable tracing for an application**:
In your `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can view the trace output in the **`trace viewer`**.

- Navigate to Trace.axd in the root of your application.
- For example, if the URL for your application is
  http://localhost/SampleApplication, navigate to
  http://localhost/SampleApplication/trace.axd to view the trace
  information for that application.
- Select the View Details link for the request that you want to
  investigate.

**Sources**

- [Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973(v=vs.140).aspx)
- [More about ASP.net tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(v=vs.140).aspx)
- [View ASP.NET Trace Information with the Trace Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: This traces HTTP requests - I want to be able to log Trace statements (System.Diagnostics) from my ASP.Net MVC application.

Comment: I see , check out this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd%28v=vs.140%29.aspx